# Can we charge ships using wave power in ocean?

Tags: electrostatics, waves, charge, power

Can we use wave power to charge any objects in the ocean?

Comment: There is recent technology which is sort of similar to this [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiwnprlo4mAAxVx7TgGHcEmC_sQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yankodesign.com%2F2022%2F08%2F19%2Fspine-like-floating-platform-harnesses-water-wave-energy%2F&usg=AOvVaw2TBpASobXlFApT1HmBvN9a&opi=89978449). So ig technically you can use it to charge the ship too

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes, and there are different schema to do this.  An example is the [Pelamis Wave Energy Converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelamis_Wave_Energy_Converter).

More generally, any source of motion is a potential source for power generation, the question is what you use that power for and how much is generated.

An example for why that question is relevant is related to different damping systems to stabilize skyscrapers.  One way to do this is to have a counterweight which passes over a set of magnets which in turn [creates an electric eddy current which opposes the motion by generating an opposing magnetic field](https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/infrastructure/a14564/the-121-story-tower-that-never-sways/).

Comment: The _other_ question is, How much drag on the forward motion of the ship\* does the wave-motion-harvester cause, and does the amount of energy harvested exceed the additional work that the ship's engines must perform because of that drag? Some wave-energy-harvesters, such as the one to which 
Harshdeep Chhabra linked, look like they might rob the ship of more energy than the machine gets from the wave motion. [\*Assuming, of course, that you want to harvest wave energy while the ship is under way.]

Comment: @SolomonSlow agree, generally most ships are concerned with stability, so a ship that relied on wave power would need a radically different design.